# Difference between target google APIs and target android

Tags: android, virtual, device, target, android-virtual-device

I'm developing android with SDK 2.3.3 using Eclipse IDE.
As you all know to run my app, I should generate virtual device.
From 'create new AVD' window, I can see many targets. 
There are 2 targets for API level 10 such as 'android 2.3.3' and Google APIs(Google Inc).
Among those targets, I'm uncertain which one I should choose.

My question is what's the difference between them.

Thanks in advance
Dan

Answer (score 144, accepted):

The Google API includes Google Maps and other Google-specific libraries.  The Android one only includes core Android libraries.

As for which one to choose, I would go with the Android API until you find that you need the Google API; such as when you need Google Maps functionality.

[Here](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html) is a link to the Google API page.

Comment: @Zack: So does that mean all the functionality of Android is also included in the corresponding Google API ?

Comment: From a developer's perspective, yes.  The Google API version adds the functionality on top of the regular Android OS.

Comment: @Zach Do you know if the actual Android phones and tablets come with Google API installed?

Comment: @Artyom: While a device isn't technically required to include the libraries that make up Google's API, it's a de facto standard.  I've yet to come across a device which doesn't include them.

Comment: Also from what I've seen, 'Google APIs' target also has ApiDemos package installed as well

Comment: That's strange because when I pick Target with Google APIs, I get `No system images installed for this target` in CPU/ABI dropdown. But if I pick generic Android 7.0 target, I can pick various Google APIs items in the CPU/ABI dropdown, and when I create a AVD with one of them, Google Maps is present and working. So, I'm confused what's the difference between picking Google APIs in Target vs in CPU/ABI.

Comment: Oh, I just found out why. See this bug report: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210223  It seems, that since some specific SDK version you aren't supposed to select Google APIs as the Target but you should select it as CPU/ABI instead.