# How to add google map to android api 8

Tags: android, google-maps

I need to extend MapActivity to create map view inside my android application. I'm using api 8. I signed up for an Android Maps API key. But in the class file I can't extend the MapActivity. When I'm trying to add "Third Party Add-Ons" inside the "SDK and AVD Manager" an error called "Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list.xml, reason: File not found" is appeared. Then I tried to "Add Add-on Site URL" by applying both "http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml" and "https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml" url's, the error message still showing.
Please help

Comment: i have solved this problem. the key point is upgrade sdk atleast api level 16.

Comment: Google API level 8 contains Maps API, but not Android API 8! In your solution API Level 16 still doesn't contains Maps API, because Maps API is only present in Google API Levels. So your key point is wrong!

Comment: @mybeck Thank you for your corrections. But I could load mapview after downloading all the updates of Android 4.0.3(API 15)

Answer (score 0):

please check if your Android project uses Google API (which includes Map Kit) as Build SDK.
There is no need to add Third Party Add-Ons or smth else.

The Android SDK don't include the Maps Kit and some other functionality. The Google API include the Android API and extend this with some more functionality like the Map Kit. Please check the following link for more details: [Difference between target google APIs and target android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914775/difference-between-target-google-apis-and-target-android)

BR,
mybecks