# API 17: Android 4.2 vs Google APIs (Google inc.) (API 17) when creating new app

Tags: android

Using Android Studio (or Eclipse with ADT plugins), when creating a new project (not AVD) what is the difference between the "Compile With" options, for example,
`API 17: Android 4.2 (Jelly Bean)`
and
`Google APIs (Google Inc.) (API 17)`?

I know the difference between the two when creating an AVD but just wondered what the difference was when it came to creating the base Android app project.

Obviously I know the difference between the different API numbers but just wondered what difference it made when creating a new project.

Thank you.

Comment: Repeat of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914775/difference-between-target-google-apis-and-target-android/5914828#5914828

Comment: sometimes when You using projects with libraries (that require Google APIs) you should use Google APIs (Google Inc.) (API 17)

Comment: I knew that creating an AVD with the Google APIs included allowed things like Maps and Play Licensing but didn't know what it did when creating a new project and not AVD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The Google API includes  Google-specific libraries.**

- **API 17: Android 4.2** (Jelly Bean) has only android API's for jelly bean
- **[Google APIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_APIs)** (Google Inc.) (API 17) has API 17: `Android 4.2 + Google API's` also that are compatible with  android 4.2

Google provides API's for various purposes eg Google Map API for showing [Google Map](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/maps.html),using [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)  in Android App. etc.

> If you want to use any such Google feature in app the you need to
>   import Google API's along with normal android API's.By selecting
>   Google APIs(API 17) you import Google libraries compatible for android
>   4.2

Check out some of the google API's [here](https://developers.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/?csw=1)

Comment: I didn't realise you had to base a project on the Google APIs; I would have thought you could include them in your code along the way like any other lib.

Answer (score 0):

i think the biggest difference is that the GoogleAPI comes along with all the common Google-libraries you could need. for example the GooglePlayServices, etc.

Comment: So if your app is using google maps you should not link google_play_services project anymore?